# Run a workflow rule across all objects once?

Tags: workflow

Suppose I have a workflow rule or a trigger to update a value when an object is edited.

How can I run the rule once globally after implementing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the rule once globally"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between your assertion that when a workflow or trigger will update a record like they were the same.

Workflows **only** fire when the record is edited so you can't just fire it without editing a record.

Triggers could be ran independently of record edits so it gives you more flexibility.

For example, consider this scenario I have a class that creates account records for me. It generally gets triggered when the criteria is met editing a record but I can use anonymous apex in the developer console to fire it independently.

In the console I can call the code and it runs.

```
Set<Id> s = new Set<Id>();
s.add('001000000000000');

dansAwesomeClass.createAccounts(s);
```

Another way to fire logic independently is to schedule the logic to run using scheduled apex. In this way you would create a class to say when you want it to run and then it runs at that interval regardless of records being edited.